# Python fastest way to find similar vector in a large matrix

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to write a python function that takes a vector(1x128), then finds the most similar column in a large non-sorted matrix (2000x128). This function called ~100000 times in application. There was no problem when I'm working on desktop PC, but it works very slow in Raspberry Pi. Here is my function;

```
def find_similar_index(a):
    d = []
    norma=np.linalg.norm(a)
    for i in range(0, 1999):
        d.append(np.abs(np.linalg.norm(a - A[:, i]))/norma)
    return np.argmin(d)
```

Can I improve anything in this function to work faster? 
Can I use GPU of Raspberry Pi for this kind of computation?

Comment: For what you're trying to obtain this sounds pretty close to the necessary number of calls (you might be able to reduce the number of calls by a small amount, but nothing extreme). I'm not familiar with Python GPU processing, so I can't help you out there.

Comment: you should just try to do `@jit` to the function. It uses numba to speed things up. It'll surely make it faster since you call ~ 0.1M times

Comment: If `A` is `(2000x128)`, thus `A[:,i]` would be of length `2000` and since you are doing `a - A[:, i]`, shouldn't `a` be of length `2000` too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
subs = (a[:,None] - A)
sq_dist = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',subs, subs)
min_idx = np.abs(sq_dist).argmin()
```

Another way to get `sq_dist` using `(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab` formula -

```
sq_dist = (A**2).sum(0) + a.dot(a) - 2*a.dot(A)
```

With `np.einsum`, that would boosted to -

```
sq_dist = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',A,A) + a.dot(a) - 2*a.dot(A)
```

Also, since the final result that we are interested in just the closest index and also those distances from `np.linalg.norm` would be positive given real numbers from the input arrays, we can skip `np.abs` and also skip the scaling the scaling down by `norma`.

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def app0(a,A): # Original approach
    d = []
    for i in range(0, A.shape[1]):
        d.append(np.linalg.norm(a - A[:, i]))
    return np.argmin(d)

def app1(a,A):
    subs = (a[:,None] - A)
    sq_dist = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',subs, subs)
    return sq_dist.argmin()

def app2(a,A):
    sq_dist = (A**2).sum(0) + a.dot(a) - 2*a.dot(A) 
    return sq_dist.argmin()

def app3(a,A):
    sq_dist = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',A,A) + a.dot(a) - 2*a.dot(A)
    return sq_dist.argmin()
```

Since, you mentioned that the `vector` is of shape `(1x128)` and you are looking for similar columns in `A` to that vector, so it seems each column is of length `128` and as such I am assuming that `A` is shaped `(128, 2000)`. With those assumptions, here's a setup and timings using the listed approaches -

```
In [194]: A = np.random.rand(128,2000)
     ...: a = np.random.rand(128)
     ...: 

In [195]: %timeit app0(a,A)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.21 ms per loop

In [196]: %timeit app1(a,A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 330 µs per loop

In [197]: %timeit app2(a,A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 287 µs per loop

In [198]: %timeit app3(a,A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 291 µs per loop

In [200]: 9210/287.0 # Speedup number
Out[200]: 32.09059233449477
```

Comment: Approach 3 is working way faster than I expected. I am really appreciated

Comment: @user2431358 Awesome! Please make sure to make corrections (if any)  in the question regarding the queries on the shapes of `a` and `A`.